# Ansible playbook is not skipping the task when variable defined is not parsed

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I am using the ansible lineinfile module to replace few lines in file. The two variables "**apache_status**" & " **collector_status**"  are passed as extra vars when running the playbook. However, when i dont pass **collector_status** , the second task is getting failed by throwing undefined variable error. I want ansible to skip the task when variable defined in task is not added in extra vars. Any help is appreciated.

Command: `ansible-playbook playbook_name --extra-vars "apache_status=TRUE"`

> ```
> - name: Enable/Disable Apache  service
>   lineinfile: 
>     path: /apache/properities
>     regexp: '^active='
>     line: active={{ apache_status }}
> - name: Enable/Disable collector 
>   lineinfile:
>     path: /apache/properities
>     regexp: '^collector='
>     line: collector={{ collector_status }}
> ```

```
"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'collector_status' is undefined"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- name: Enable/Disable Apache  service
  lineinfile: 
    path: /apache/properities
    regexp: '^active='
    line: active={{ apache_status }}
- name: Enable/Disable collector 
  lineinfile:
    path: /apache/properities
    regexp: '^collector='
    line: collector={{ collector_status }}
  when: collector_status is defined
```